# ISSUE API PRESTASHOP 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I currently have a problem with the prestashop API.

I'm trying to update the amount of a combination of a product.

```
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://myurl.com/api/combinations/15544');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_PUT);

$request->setQueryData(array(
  'io_format' => 'JSON'
));

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
  'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
  'Host' => 'myurl.com',
  'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
  'Accept' => '*/*',
  'User-Agent' => 'PostmanRuntime/7.19.0',
  'Authorization' => 'Basic HIDDEN',
  'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
));

$request->setBody('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <combination>
            <id>15544</id>
            <quantity>105</quantity>
            <location></location>
            <ean13></ean13>
            <isbn></isbn>
            <upc></upc>
            <upplier_reference></upplier_reference>
            <wholesale_price></wholesale_price>
            <price></price>
            <weight></weight>
            <unit_price_impact></unit_price_impact>
            <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
            <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
            <id_product>195</id_product>
            <reference>E1903XLN</reference>
        </combination>
        </prestashop>');

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

The response from the server is correct.

When I get the declination with a get here is the return:

```
{
    "combination": {
        "id": 15544,
        "id_product": "195",
        "location": "",
        "ean13": "",
        "isbn": "",
        "upc": "",
        "quantity": "105",
        "reference": "E1903XLN",
        "supplier_reference": "",
        "wholesale_price": "0.000000",
        "price": "0.000000",
        "ecotax": "0.000000",
        "weight": "0.000000",
        "unit_price_impact": "0.000000",
        "minimal_quantity": "1",
        "low_stock_threshold": null,
        "low_stock_alert": "0",
        "default_on": null,
        "available_date": "0000-00-00",
        "associations": {
            "product_option_values": [
                {
                    "id": "28"
                },
                {
                    "id": "32"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless on prestashop in the backoffice I do not see the changes:

[Image of the BO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJS1b.png)

Do you have an idea or solution ?
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

To set an update of stock quantity for your combination you need to talk with the object StockAvailable.

Have a nice day :) !

Comment: Absolutely, I found the answer but I did not have time to update the post to give the solution.

thank you very much